# How to speed up recreating cluster index

Tags: sql-server, indexing

In SQL Server, there is no option for altering the cluster index if i want to add one new column to cluster index definition. The only option is to drop and create cluster index with new definition.

From what I understand, drop and create of cluster index is a very costly and time consuming for high volume tables.

Cluster index recreate rebuilds all the nonclustered indexes on a table which can be very expensive.

The question to this forum "is there anyway we can speed up cluster index recreating"

The one workaround what I can think is to drop all non-cluster index before recreating cluster index. Will this approach work ?

Comment: The *clustered* index orders the data itself on disk. Altering it means reordering all the data on disk. That's expensive no matter which database you use. In SQL Server Enterprise edition you can avoid downtime by using the `ONLINE = ON` hint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
CREATE .... WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON)
```

Instead of

```
DROP ... 
CREATE ...
```

This means the non clustered indexes only have to be updated once (to include the new key column). Not twice - first to use the physical rid and then again to use the new CI key.

The [DROP_EXISTING](http://sqlmag.com/database-high-availability/use-create-indexs-dropexisting-clause-when-recreating-clustered-index) clause tells SQL Server that the existing clustered index is being dropped but that a new one will be added in its place, letting SQL Server defer updating the nonclustered index until the new clustered index is in place..

Additionally, SQL Server won't rebuild the nonclustered index at all if the clustered index key doesn't change and is defined as UNIQUE, which isn't an obvious performance benefit of defining a clustered index as UNIQUE

Example

```
CREATE TABLE #T
(
A INT,
B INT,
C INT
)

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX ON #T(A)

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX ON #T(A,B) WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON)

DROP TABLE #T
```

Comment: The OP can add the `ONLINE = ON` hint to rebuild the index in the background and avoid downtime

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Isn't the process of rebuilding the clustered index with `ONLINE ON` similar to building the nonclustered indexes with the same hint? As there is a small downtime when the RDBMS switches from the current index to the newly created one?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu and all this time the table is available for querying. That's a huge advantage when dealing with large tables. It also means you can apply changes immediately instead of waiting for eg the weekend

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, true. I just wanted to know if there is a small downtime when the switch occurs from the old-index to the new-index.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu:there is small amount of time where you can see locking,blockings...http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-830-unicorns-rainbows-and-online-index-operations/

Comment: Thank you @TheGameiswar I just wanted confirmation about this.