# Modifying an existing index: Create index with drop_existing=on vs. alter index statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am new to index maintenance. I see most of our indexes are modified using `create index` with `drop_existing = on`. For example:

```
create nonclustered index ixn_SomeTable__SomeIndexName_ic1 
on dbo.SomeTable                ( Column1 )
include                         ( Column2, IncludeThisNewColumn3 )
with ( sort_in_tempdb = on, drop_existing = on, online = on, fillfactor = 95 ) on [SomeFileGroup]
go
```

but I see TSQL also has `alter index` statement.

Questions -

1. What does the `drop_existing=on` do? Does it just drops the index if it exists and recreates it or does it save on rebuilding the index (re-indexing data etc) if the modifications don't really need rebuilding of index. (for example including a column in a non-clustered index)?
2. What is the difference between `create index with drop_existing = on` and `alter index`? When do I absolutely have to use one or the other?
3. Does the index become unavailable when the modifications to the index are in progress and is there a way to keep the unavailable time to minimum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What does the drop_existing=on do? Does it just drops the index if it exists and recreates it or does it save on rebuilding the index (re-indexing data etc)

The `DROP_EXISTING` clause tells SQL Server that the existing clustered index is being dropped but that a new one will be added in its place, letting SQL Server defer updating the nonclustered index until the new clustered index is in place

> does it save on rebuilding the index (re-indexing data etc) if the modifications don't really need rebuilding of index. (for example including a column in a non-clustered index)?

SQL Server won't rebuild the non clustered index at all if the clustered index key doesn't change and is defined as UNIQUE

> What is the difference between create index with drop_existing = on and alter index? When do I absolutely have to use one or the other?

alter index is used to Rebuild/Reorg index..I don't see any comparison with Create

> Does the index become unavailable when the modifications to the index are in progress and is there a way to keep the unavailable time to minimum?

When you use `DROP EXISTING` clause,index will be available for most of the time..Index will require an Exclusive lock at the end,but this blocking will be very  short

**References:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41096665/2975396
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx
http://sqlmag.com/database-high-availability/use-create-indexs-dropexisting-clause-when-recreating-clustered-index